# How can I get distance between two points on Earth from PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm getting an unexpected value from a PostGIS distance query, and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to find the distance between two points on Earth.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_Point(50.7678,6.091499)::geography,
  ST_Point(52.525592,13.369545)::geography
) as distance;
```

... returns `827757.672533206`, or about 827.7km.

However, if I calculate this distance with an open source library I'm using, or using any one of several online calculators, I get 538.6km. Something is obviously amiss.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using PostGIS 2.1.7 with PostgreSQL 9.4.1

Comment: As a rule of consistency, the axis order used by PostGIS and many other GIS software is always Cartesian (X Y) or (long lat).

Comment: e.g. `SELECT ST_AsLatLonText(ST_Point(50.7678,6.091499));` returns 6°5'29.396"N 50°46'4.080"E

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result is correct, the input is not. [ST_Point](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) accepts input as `(lon,lat)` while you're verifying it as `(lat,lon)`.