# Calculate distance between two coordinates using postgres?

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, postgis

I´ve got a job offer to work with postgres and I have not much idea of it. The guy told me to build a simple data base which automatically calculates the distance to my house from a list of some other places (bars, pharmacies, museums, whatever...) everything given in geocoordinates.

I have already installed postgres, also postgis and create a data base. May you give me some hints about how I should do this task? Is there any tutorial or resource I could use to make this tasks easier? Should I use postgis?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213790/how-can-i-get-distance-between-two-points-on-earth-from-postgis , help yourself.

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS will do this easily.  Boundless Geo have an excellent [PostGIS tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/).  I also recommend you are familiar with Ch3 & 4 of the PostGIS manual.

I strongly advise you to learn & understand the difference between projected and unprojected coordinates if you're going to be working with spatial data. Projected means the coordinates have been taken from a 'round earth' and adjusted or projected onto to a flat map page (with coordinates normally given in feet or metres depending on the properties of the projection used). This enables computationally efficient normal cartesian calculations to be done for distance, area, direction, intersection, contains etc. There are trade offs for using projections- You can't preserve all of area, distance, shape, direction when you project a curved line or surface onto a flat map. Different projections are optimised for different trade-offs. Calculations on projected data are only accurate over a relatively small portion of the earth's surface. There are many map projections available to suit various needs and localities.  If you are going to be working with projected data, you need to pick a projection that suits your purposes and location.  If you don't understand projections, your queries can easily produce garbage without realising it.

Unprojected data (ie, raw Lat/Lon coordinates which is what you have) involve much more complicated calculations as they are done on the curved surface of the spheroid representing the earth.  There are a number of reference coordinate systems that are used to express Lat/Lon, however the most common is "[WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)" (which is what "GPS" coordinates are expressed in).

PostGIS objects (in the form of "simple features" as defined by the OGC) can be stored as either "geometry" types (projected coordinates) or "geography" types (unprojected Lon/Lat in WGS84: note the order, a common source of confusion!).  As a bit of a wrinkle, Lon/Lat (order again!) can also be stored as a "pseudo projected" geometry type (typically with a projection SRID of '4326' for WGS84 Lon/Lat).

The method you use to calculate distance will depend on how you choose to store your points ('geometry' or 'geography').

See [ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) from the PostGIS docs for excellent examples of measuring distance using both geometry and geography points.  Note, if you wish to calculate projected map distances you will need to pick an appropriate map projection and use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Transform.html) to project your points to the appropriate spatial reference system (currently in SRID 4326- "GPS" coordinates).  For only a few points the difference won't be at all noticeable, but once you start doing lots of more complex spatial queries, the difference can be significant.  PostGIS has a lot more functions for geometry types than for geography types which may influence your decision. Also see [ST_DistanceSpheroid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) for another possibility for calculating distance from Lon/Lat coordinates.

To start with, I'd store your points as 'geography' to simplify your experiments.  Your distances will then be 'great circle' calcs in metres and you won't have to worry about projections initially.